# segmentation fault in c while coding Vigenère’s cipher

Tags: c, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, cs50, vigenere

I am really new to coding and I have been teaching myself how to code by using EDX.org. This week I have been studying about Cryptography and I have to create a Vigenère’s cipher. I wrote the code and for the most part, it's correct. However when I compiled the program, it's showing a segmentation error. I have been trying to figure our why this is happening and I am totally stuck. Could you take a look at my code and tell me whats wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int index(int k, int c); 

int main (int argc, string argv[1])
{
    //check for correct criteria 
    if (argc = 2, isalpha(argv[1]))
    {
        string text = GetString(); 
        string key = argv[1]; //store key word
        int Totalshift = strlen(key); //number of shift for keyword


        int shift = 0; 

        //loops over the whole text
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i <n; i++ )
        {
            char p= text[i];
            char k = toupper(key[shift]); //Upper case for each character

           if (isupper(p))
            {
               //convert to 0 index
                 p = p - 65; 
                 k = k - 65; 

                int crypt= index (k , p); 

                printf("%c", crypt+65);

                shift= (shift+1) %Totalshift; 
            }
            else if (islower(p))
            {

                p = p - 97; 
                k = k - 65; 

                int crypt= index (k , p); 

                printf("%c", crypt+97);

                shift= (shift+1) %Totalshift; 
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("%c", p);
            }


        }
            printf("\n");
        }




    //error message
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        return 1; 
    }


}

//index function
int index(int k, int p)
{
   return (k+p)% 26; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string`

*No.* **Never, ever hide pointers.**

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

Then:

```
//check for correct criteria 
if (argc = 2, isalpha(argv[1]))
```

Here, you *assign* to the variable (parameters behave like local variables in that respect) the value `2`, thus destroying the previous value (which holds the number of arguments given to the program). The result is the value which was assigned, thus `2`. Then, there's the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator): You discard that `2`, and then call `isalpha(argv[1])`, which clearly shows why you **should always turn on warnings** and **never, ever hide pointers**:

`argv[1]` is of type `char *`, thus a **pointer** to a character array (or, as we know in this case, a character array terminated with `'\0'`, which is called a *C string*). Since `isalpha` [takes an `int` as parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isalpha.html) the value of the pointer ("the memory address") is implicitly converted to (a probably very large) `int` value. Quoting from above link, emphasis mine:

> The c argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is representable as an unsigned char or equal to the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, **the behavior is undefined**.

Which is possibly the source of the segmentation fault.

Finally, that `GetString` really looks fishy to me. Assuming that it allocates some memory (for the string that it presumably reads from the user) ... where do you *free* that memory? Is it really allocating memory, or possibly returning a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration (a local variable, so to say)?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I appreciate your answer. Both GetString and the string is from the CS50 library which is mentioned above. The problem with the operators and getalpha that you mentioned solved the problem. Now the program is running correctly.